# RDF representation of sentences

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, rdf

I need to represent sentences in RDF format.

In other words "John likes coke" would be automatically represented as:

```
Subject : John
Predicate : Likes
Object : Coke
```

Does anyone know where I should start? Are there any programs which can do this automatically or would I need to do everything from scratch?

Comment: Note this is still an active area of research. The best parsers tend to work well on small sentences, like your example, but will tend to fail miserably on "real world" sentences.

Comment: Could you give us the intended representation of any real, 10+ words long sentence ? (e.g. "Anarchism is a political philosophy that advocates stateless societies often defined as self-governed voluntary institutions.")
[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408867/representing-natural-language-as-rdf?rq=1) looks like asking how much of what you ask for is feasible, and the answer is not much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you want the **typed dependencies** of a sentence, e.g. for `John likes coke`:

```
 nsubj(likes-2, John-1)
 dobj(likes-2, coke-3)
```

I'm not aware of any dependency parser that directly produces RDF. However, many of them produce parses in a standardized tab limited representation known as [CoNLL-X](http://nextens.uvt.nl/~conll/#dataformat), and it shouldn't be too hard to convert from CoNLL-X to RDF.

**Open Source Dependency parsers**

There are a number of parsers to choose from that extract typed dependencies, including the following *state-of-art* open source options:

- [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) - see [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp?query=John%20likes%20coke.).
- [MaltParser](http://maltparser.org/)
- [MSTParser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mstparser/)

The **Stanford Parser** includes a pre-trained model for parsing English. To get typed dependencies you'll need to use the flag `-outputFormat typedDependencies`.

For the **MaltParser** you can download an English model [here](http://maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html).

The **MSTParser** includes a small 200 sentence English training set that you can use to create you're own English parsing model. However, training on this little data will hurt the accuracy of the resulting parser. So, if you decide to use this parser, you are probably better off using the pretrain model available [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies/mst-eisner.mod.gz).

All of the pretrained models linked above produce parses according to the Stanford Dependency formalism ([ACL paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W/W08/W08-1301.pdf), and [manual](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf)).

Of these three, the Stanford Parser is the most accurate. The MaltParser is the fastest, with some configurations of this package being able to parse [1800 sentences in only 8 seconds](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/lrecstanforddeps_final_final.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use output from [Link Parser](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/), available under a GPL-compatible license.  You can define a translation layer between these outputs and your RDF nodes as needed.

Check out [this demo](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html) on your "John likes coke" example!