# 'Tree' object has no attribute 'triples', stanford parser via nltk

Tags: python, tree, nltk, stanford-nlp, dependency-tree

When I am using the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443330/how-do-i-do-dependency-parsing-in-nltk) I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'triples'
```

The version of the nltk I am using is 3.2.4, python 2.7. Any ideas of how to solve it are highly appreciated!

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
path_to_jar = 'path_to/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser.jar'
path_to_models_jar = 'path_to/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser-3.4.1-models.jar'
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar,     path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)

result = dependency_parser.raw_parse('I shot an elephant in my sleep')
dep = result.next()
print list(dep.triples())
```

Comment: The help string for `StanfordDependencyParser` mentions `parse.triples()` and `parse.trees()`, suggesting that the result should be a special parse object that can be viewed in different ways. In fact, `raw_parse()` returns a sequence of `Tree()` objects, not triples. Do you _need_ the triples for some reason? If not, just change your code to `print(dep)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am really interested in the triples or something similar to Open IE https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html