# NLTK CoreNLPDependencyParser: Failed to establish connection

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use the Stanford Parser through NLTK, following the example [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPDependencyParser%20tutorial%20here).

I follow the first two lines of the example (with the necessary import)

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPDependencyParser
dep_parser = CoreNLPDependencyParser(url='http://localhost:9000')
parse, = dep_parser.raw_parse('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
```

but I get an error saying:

```
[...] Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused"
```

I realize that it must be an issue with trying to connect to the url given as input to the constructor.

```
dep_parser = CoreNLPDependencyParser(url='http://localhost:9000')
```

What url should I be connecting to, if not this? If this is correct, what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first download and run the CoreNLP server on `localhost:9000`.

1) download CoreNLP at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
2) unzip the files to some directory then run the following command in the that directory to start the server

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Ref: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

The result of the above code is like

```
>>> print(parse.to_conll(4))
The DT  4   det
quick   JJ  4   amod
brown   JJ  4   amod
fox NN  5   nsubj
jumps   VBZ 0   ROOT
over    IN  9   case
the DT  9   det
lazy    JJ  9   amod
dog NN  5   nmod
.   .   5   punct
```

---

You can also start the server via NLTK API (need to configure the `CORENLP_HOME` environment variable first)

```
os.environ["CORENLP_HOME"] = "dir"
client = corenlp.CoreNLPClient()
# do something
client.stop()
```

Comment: Does it mean that we don't need to run the `java` command if we go with the latter approach via `NLTK` API? Also, what needs to be installed and imported for this solution? Mine complains `NameError: name 'CoreNLPClient' is not defined`

Comment: Online version: [Stanford POS tagger online](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)